# Exclude posts with specific keyword in Blogger's Popular Widget (using Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I've tried looking for a Javascript that **exclude** posts with specific labels on Popular Posts Widget. I learned that we can't directly retrieve posts label data on blogger. This is what I found.

> For Popular Post widget the only data retrieved for this widget is..
>
> data:title data:thumbnail data:snippet
>
> And other data coming from the widget body settings like show hide
>   thumbnails or snippets etc..
>
> This widget could not filter out a specific post with a label as the
>   data label for posts is not available to check.
>
> What you can do is to use your Blogger feed to retrieve the post by
>   label using javascript JSONp format and render the output according to
>   your needs.
>
> Or use javascript to hide a specific keyword you provided in post
>   title which will diaplay the post with the specified keyword instead.
>
> Anyway, what you are trying to achieve is beyond Blogger unitial
>   product and it is best you send you questions to stackoverflow.com
>   website and experts/ developers there will certainly help out.
>
> Regards.

source: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/8Kq0NQfX1Z0

So, how do I Exclude posts with specific keyword in their Title from appearing on Popular Posts widget?

thank you.